# How to get actual client IP using C in linux systems instead of localhost address

Tags: linux, networking, ip, c, socket

I am trying to read IP address in ubuntu system using C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) { 


int status; 
struct addrinfo hints, *p; 
struct addrinfo *servinfo; 
char ipstr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
char hostname[128];


memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); 


hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;    
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;  
hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;  


gethostname(hostname, 128);


if ((status = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &servinfo)) == -1) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status)); 
    exit(1); 
}       


for (p=servinfo; p!=NULL; p=p->ai_next) { 
    struct in_addr  *addr;  
    if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { 
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr; 
        addr = &(ipv->sin_addr);  
    } 
    else { 
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr; 
        addr = (struct in_addr *) &(ipv6->sin6_addr); 
    }
        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr); 
 
} 
  
    printf("Address: %s\n", ipstr);
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); 


return 0;


 }
```

I am not getting actual client IP instead I am getting 127.0.1.1 whereas I was expecting 192.168.x.x When I comment 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts file I get the actual IP but this solution is not feasible

Answer (score 1):

This question is more of a programmer's question and possibly belongs on StackOverflow.   As it happens it's already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/265978/453851

The upshot is you need to use [getifaddrs](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)

To explain why your code didn't work...  What your code does is to find the hostname of the local machine and then ask for the IP address of that hostname.  You'll find that your hostname is recorded in `/etc/hosts` as `127.0.0.1` and `::1`.  This is a common configuration in linux.  When a program is tryong to talk to something on the local machine it dialling out to the network at all.

Comment: The only problem with getifaddrs is it is not POSIX compliant

Comment: @rac10 your question was tagged Linux and asked "in ubuntu", if you want posix compliant, it's better to ask for posix compliant.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8645566/453851) there's no posix complaint way to do what you want (enumerating every IP).  But if you just want one IP then the link may help.

Comment: @rac10 It looks like getifaddrs is available in linux, OSX, BSD, and GNU Hurd.  Which other "posix" operating systems do you care about?  Sometimes functions get adopted by all major posix OS before posix officially standardises them.

Comment: Thanks @Philip Couling ,can you help in sharing standard example of getting IP  using getifaddrs

Comment: @rac10 see the link I referenced in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/265978/453851

Comment: I checked example it will list multiple address,so how do I get active IP which is used

Comment: Can you suggest how do I get active IP?Will it be first in the list?

Comment: All IPs are active.  They are all used for *something*.  It really depends what you want this IP for.  But remember a machine can have many IP addresses.  Particularly if you have more than one interface or if you are using IPv6.

Comment: I am creating TCP or UDP connection,so wanted which IP will it go through

Comment: @rac10, which IP address it will "go through" depends on the system's routing table. An IP address identifies an interface, and on a machine with multiple interfaces which interface will be used depends on where the destination IP is.

Comment: @spuck Is there any alternate method to get the IP?

Comment: @rac10, it's up to the routing layer to figure out which interface/IP a connection should use. IP addresses are not assigned to clients, they are assigned to interfaces.

Comment: @spluck So there is no recommended C program  in linux to get single IP which is in use?

Comment: Why do you need the IP?  As @spunk mentioned above, when you establish a TCP connection to a remote host, you don't specify your local address, the operating system selects a suitable address based on the routing table and the destination address.

Comment: @AndyDalton Local IP is needed for tracking purpose

Comment: @rac10, does it have to be a C program, or would you be happy with a script that could give you all the IP addresses on the machine?

Comment: Tracking what? You could just get the IP address of the socket after you connect

Comment: @spuck It has to be C program